# Deactivated nvidia for longer battery, xrandr doesn't show HDMI

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, bbswitch

As everyone knows, nvidia drivers don't work well on Ubuntu. I deactivated my RTX 2060 nvidia card on my Lenovo Legion Y540 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (keeping its use on Windows for gaming) doing the following (from [there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1765363)):

I checked `Enable hybrid graphics` in my BIOS; then,

`sudo aptitude install bbswitch-dkms`

and

`sudo nvim /etc/modules`

added `bbswitch` and reloaded.

I then switched to `intel` with:

`sudo prime-select intel`

And turned off nvidia card for lower consumption with

`sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF`

My consumption went from like 40W to 11W, which is great, but now `xrandr` gives

```
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900     144.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1368x768     144.00    59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720     144.00    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   1024x576     144.00    59.90    59.82  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540      144.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   864x486      144.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405      144.00    59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   640x400       85.08  
   640x360      144.00    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I just tried to plug in an HDMI monitor, and now it turned on the nvidia card again (while `prime-select query` still gives `intel` as a result), my power consumption is at 43W. I have to run `sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF` again.

Does anyone know how to deactivate the nvidia card, yet still be able to connect external monitors? Maybe a USB-c adapter could do the trick if there is no other way?

lspci output:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f11 (rev a1)
```